# Could not find Angular Material core theme - How to add Angular Material css to Liferay Portlet

Tags: css, angular-material, liferay-7

I am building a Liferay Angular portlet that uses angular material inputs and some inputs are not rendering well at all. I am guessing that some CSS/JS is missing, but I can not figure it out what exactly.

My styling css file looks like this:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber";
```

Also, when I inspect with Developer tools, I see the following warning:

```
Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected.
```

I have also tried referencing the css file from the AppComponent with styleUrls: ["/o/<my-portlet_name>/lib/app/styling.css"], but without any luck.

So, my question is - **How to reference a CSS file within an Angular Portlet in Liferay ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read over and over again [this](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017888072-Using-Angular-in-Your-Portlets) article and finally I made the following changes:

1. changed the `styling.css` file into `styling.scss`
2. changed its content to `@import "../../../../../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber";` - I am not sure why are necessary 5 of `../`, I was expecting that by using `~` to know where `node_modules` folder is
3. added the following line in the `property` attribute of the `@Component` annotation in my Portlet: `"com.liferay.portlet.header-portlet-css=/lib/app/styling.css"` - yes, the extension is `.css` and not `.scss`